# How to make SQL SERVER Partition when there is no Group identifier on the original table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, partition

I have the following table:

| Name | Rol | FirstDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Leader | 01-01-2020 |
| Bob | Follower | 01-05-2020 |
| Charles | Follower | 03-06-2020 |
| Art | Leader | 04-01-2021 |
| Will | Leader | 05-01-2022 |
| Susy | Follower | 06-01-2023 |

I want to get this:

| Name | Rol | GroupId | MemberId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Leader | 1 | 1 |
| Bob | Follower | 1 | 2 |
| Charles | Follower | 1 | 3 |
| Art | Leader | 2 | 1 |
| Will | Leader | 3 | 1 |
| Susy | Follower | 3 | 2 |

Whenever the Rol shows a Leader, I want a new group. Inside each group, I want a MemberId.

I have tried to solve this using PARTITION OVER.

The above table is not the real table, but it serves the purpose of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Now that we have a meaningful order, the next step is something call **gaps and islands**. This is one of those things I have a mental block about and have to Google every time I do it... and if I have to do that, I may as well save a layer of translation and send you straight to the source.

Comment: Gaps and Islands. That's new for me. I will google.